# SSL protocol paper "Investigations about SSL"

Tags: tls

In several papers, I see the quote of the following security paper, which concerns SSL:

> ```
> EADS Defence and Security Systems SA. Investigations about ssl.
> http://www.eucybervote.org/Reports/MSI-WP2-D7V1-V1.0-02.htm.
> ```

Unfortunately, I can't find it anywhere, by checking the address directly or by using a web crawler. Where could it be available on the Internet (if it still is)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems `eucybervote.org` isn't available anymore. You can try [the web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080616051850/http://www.eucybervote.org/Reports/MSI-WP2-D7V1-V1.0-02.htm).